# EDIFACT Mapping using JAVA

Tags: java, encoding, special-characters, edi, edifact

I am trying to map EDIFACT files using java.

The data I'm using is encoded and it looks like this:
UNBIATB11AMS135682300687X

I'm expecting this format:
UNH+1+SBRRES:09:3:1A'

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Could you pls. add more details? The question us unclear

Comment: @aholbreich, is there any tool/plugin that convert the ascii separators to the normal ones (FS,GS,US ---> " : ", " ' ", " + ")

Answer (score 2):

Your text seems to contain `0x1D`, `0x1F`, and `0x1C` characters.

If you replace `0x1D` with `+`, `0x1F` with `:`, and `0x1C` with `'`, you get:

`UNB+IATB:1+1A+MS+13568:230+0687+++X'`

You probably shouldn't replace, but simply parse using those non-displayable characters, but if you need displayable, you can do this:

```
s = s.replace('\u001D', '+').replace('\u001F', ':').replace('\u001C', '\'');
```

Or replace with whatever characters is not otherwise in the data. That is likely why they use those non-displayable characters, because they are guaranteed to not be in the text data. Remember, the computer doesn't care whether a character is displayable, only humans do.

Comment: The characters are displayed as FS GS US on notepad++.
I'm trying to understand what is that type of encoding and how to handle this

Comment: @MarwanFahmi Remember, EDIFACT doesn't mandate specific separator characters. The `UNA` record can specify whatever characters the sender wants to use as a separator characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, @Andreas.

Therefore, what is your recommendation in order to map this edifcat file to a structured human readable dataset (csv)?

Comment: @MarwanFahmi You decide on a CSV structure, you parse the EDIFACT lines, and map the values to your CSV structure, e.g. for the `UNB` record above, you might decide to put the `MS` value in column 10 of your CSV. But that's up to you how they map.

Comment: do you have any input on how to make that automated mapping an EDIFACT file that gets pushed every day on a machine?

Comment: Yes @MarwanFahmi - you use a data translator.  There's a free one called BOTS written in Python.  There's also many commercial packages that not only scale, but also handle all your partner management, communication (like AS2) and audit trails.  Easier to work in maps than it is in code (IMO)

Comment: Looking at your UNB, notice that the _Syntax Identifier_ is set to `IATB`. The default delimiters for `Level B` are the control codes that @Andreas  stated.  http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/texts/d422_d.htm#p5.2